# how to use |datadirectory| to display an image in picturebox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, picturebox

I knew that |datadirectory| is the path to the current user's roaming application data folder defined by the operating system the app was installed on. But what I am going to implement here is that I was trying to call the image's path directly from the current data folder, instead of using a full path from the root. The example is below(which is not working because it says there are illegal characters in the path, but the idea is like that):

```
pictureBoxItem1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"|DataDirectory|\Images\example.jpg");
```

the one that I'm currently use:

```
pictureBoxItem1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:/Users/xxx/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/xxx/testing/Images/example.jpg");
```

Is there any other way to display data instead of using a full specified path?

Comment: you can use relative paths instead of giving entire path

Comment: how? im kinda new to these programming stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24764353/load-picturebox-image-in-c-sharp-from-file-in-relative-path) where in one of the solution he expalins about [PictureBox.Load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6ak7was(v=vs.110).aspx) method. This will help you.

Comment: Thank you sir. I never knew the existence of 'relative path'. ._.