# How to give a dynamic file path in Image.Fromfile() in C#?

Tags: c#, image, winforms, path, fromfile

I want to change an image in `WinForms` based on a result.

```
if(x == true)
{
 // Show image 1
else
{
 // show image 2
```

I saw that I can use `Image.Fromfile("Image path")`. But I have to use an image path something like this `@"C:\test\test1.jpg"`.

So, is there any way that I can give a dynamic file path?

For example, if I open the project from another computer, this file path might change.

Thank you!

Comment: And how would you get the path at first?

Comment: It is just the location where I save the images.

Comment: Is this image part of application or user will browse ?

Comment: I saved these images locally in my computer

Comment: how would you tell the program where the images are stored? At some point, *"where I saved the images"* won't be enough, else if your program can read minds

Comment: Okay, so there isn´t any way to give the file path without hard coding?

Comment: How to give a dynamical file path to an image? Easy, just create a variable, assign the desired value to it, and use it as the path to the image. You should focus in your question  to the real problem whatever it is. Distributing files with your application? Getting the path of the executable? I would advice editing your question and providing more details on the actual problem.

Comment: There are a number of options you could try in the below post.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24764353/load-picturebox-image-in-c-sharp-from-file-in-relative-path
have you checked the above post?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a PictureBox control set the ImageLocation property with the path, example:

pictureBox1.ImageLocation = @"C:\test\test1.jpg"